# List dot point for the first row in Chrome

Tags: css, list, google-chrome

I have used the following css as drop down feature for the page, however the dot point for the first row is displaying at the back of the row unless I put something in front of the list, any ideas?
it's only happening to chrome, fine with IE
thanks all

```css
.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-box+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 99%;
  border-radius: 0px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #6ab845;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  background: #004624;
}

.toggle-box+label+div {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.toggle-box:checked+label+div {
  display: block;
}

.toggle-box+label:before {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #565656;
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}

.toggle-box:checked+label:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
```

```html
<input class="toggle-box" type="checkbox" id="header1">

<label for="header1">

    <span style="FONT-SIZE: 15px">March 2017</span>

    </label>
<div>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not entirely clear. What is a dot point? Which list are we talking about? And, is there supposed to be a difference in how the snippet looks in different browsers?

Comment: sorry about the delay, I have added list content for the code, if you run the code snippet it will show fine in IE, but in Chrome the dot point of the first list row has been pushed to the end of the row

Comment: any one could help with this?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason this is happening is because the dropdown isn't contained inside the label. A few ways to fix that:

1) You can restructure the HTML to wrap everything in a div and contain everything that way, but it would be a total re-write.

2) or you can just use the small CSS changes which will get everything working. Add a `float: left` to the div containing the List. and then remove the margins from the unordered-list `margin: 0;` I've updated the snippet. Also I removed a few un-needed margins as I didn't think it looked right anymore.

```css
.toggle-box {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-box+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 99%;
  border-radius: 0px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #6ab845;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  background: #004624;
}

.toggle-box+label+div {
  display: none;
  float: left;
}

.toggle-box+label+div+ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.toggle-box:checked+label+div {
  display: block;
}

.toggle-box+label:before {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #565656;
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}

.toggle-box:checked+label:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
```

```html
<input class="toggle-box" type="checkbox" id="header1">

<label for="header1">

    <span style="FONT-SIZE: 15px">March 2017</span>

    </label>
<div>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
</div>
```